# The package `` depends on `ink_env`, with features: `ink-experimental-engine` but `ink_env` does not have these features

Tags: ink, testing, unit-tests

I want to write tests and found [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69829061/how-can-i-set-a-caller-in-ink-contract-unit-testing-function) that potentially soles my problem, but made exactly all what is recommended but still have the same issue.

I have added on top of my module with tests following line `#[cfg(feature = "ink-experimental-engine")]` and added dependency to my `Cargo.toml` like `ink-experimental-engine = ["ink_env/ink-experimental-engine"]`.

I was looking at on the documentation page of ink! under key word: `set_caller` but haven't found anything.

Comment: The experimental engine doesn't exist anymore. Its just part of ink now so you don't need to add this macro.

Comment: Thanks, fell free to answer and I will close the question as solved.

Comment: Np, I've updated the original answer on SO as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The experimental engine doesn't exist anymore. Its just part of ink now so you don't need to add this macro. This happened around [March 2022](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/1164#issuecomment-1059293430).